# trying to get the count of employee based on year of join using decode getting native error

Tags: mysql

```
   id   empjoindate
   1    1980-12-12 00:00:00 
   2    1981-11-11 00:00:00 
   3    1980-12-12 00:00:00 
   4    1982-11-11 00:00:00 
   5    1982-11-11 00:00:00 
   6    1983-12-12 00:00:00 



   SELECT SUM(DECODE(year(empjoindate),1980,1,0))"1980"
        , SUM(DECODE(year(empjoindate),1981,1,0))"1981"
        , SUM(DECODE(year(empjoindate),1982,1,0))"1982"
        , SUM(DECODE(year(empjoindate),1983,1,0))"1983"
        , COUNT(*)Total 
     FROM employeejoin;
```

Comment: And using decode because?

Answer (score 0):

DECODE method is oracle not MySQL method,
instead use CASE WHEN ELSE

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN year(empjoindate)= 1980 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1980",
SUM(CASE WHEN year(empjoindate)= 1981 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1981",
SUM(CASE WHEN year(empjoindate)= 1982 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "1982"  
FROM employeejoin;
```